# Python Clock Flickering [Pygame]

Tags: python, pygame, clock, flicker

I am writing a program in python (with pygame) that will display information on an LCD using a Raspberry Pi.

[image: My Python Clock Code]

Basically, on the screenshot it is fine but when I run the code, the Time: and the time after it flickers...
I have tried removing the `pygame.display.update()` but when I do that it just makes the Time area disappear altogether.

For anyone who can't see the screenshot, or wants to copy/paste the code segment for testing, here it is.

```
while True:
    ##################
    #CLOCK CODE START#
    ##################
    theTime = "Time: " + str(time.strftime("%H:%M"))
    timeText = menu_font.render(str(theTime), True, (255,255,255), (0,0,0))
    screen.blit(timeText, (10, 190))
    pygame.display.update()
    ################
    #CLOCK CODE END#
    ################
```

You may have to remove the indentation in the code, I just took the required part out of my program. You will also have to `import time,pygame` at the top of the program.

If you need anything else, just message me!

Comment: What do you mean by flickers?

Comment: Thanks for replying, I solved the problem, but by flickering I meant that the clock would disappear and reappear really quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found the solution about 2 minutes after I posted it.

Outside of that code, I had this:

```
    events = pygame.event.get()
    pygame.event.pump()
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
```

The 'flickering' was caused by the screen being re-cleared in the loop.

```
    events = pygame.event.get()
    pygame.event.pump()
    #screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
```

So you can just comment out the `screen.fill` to stop it.